# Laravel Controller loading another controllers method :: Strange Logic Error

Tags: php, laravel, methods, routes, controller

I am using Laravel 7.x, I have a controller which when called in the routes, instead of loading its own called method, will rather load the method of a different controller, I don't know how and why?

I.e. Controller-A executes Controller-B methods which was not called.

So, I am calling the route below from my web.php directory.

```
Route::get('/testx', 'ControllerA@show_table');
```

but it loads another ControllerB's method instead thereby loading the wrong route. Does laravel cache controllers? Its a strange logic error to me.

Comment: try `php artisan route:clear` (laravel may be caching routes, not controllers)

Comment: Are you sure there is only one `/testx` route in your web.php?

Comment: You probably have a wildcard route for `/{something}` in your routes file. Make sure that route is below everything else, especially the `/testx` route

Comment: Thanks @zlatan, thats the only route in the web.php file.

Comment: Thanks @Berto99, i have tried the command but still the same.

Comment: Thanks @aynber, removed all routes from the web.php file, i have just this testx route.

Comment: try removing all the routes and then run `php artisan route:clear` and check if it still fire the other method (btw, how are you sure that it's calling the other one?)

Comment: @Berto99 Its even stranger now, as i have deleted the controller i suspected it was going to, but its still popping up the same error.

Comment: @Berto99 how i knew it was going to another controller was that when i try to open the route from my browser, it will pop up the error below, which is from my dashboard page in the view directory.  :::ERROR CODE START:: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: calc (View: /home/website/domains/example.com/public_html/members/resources/views/components/inc_stats_users.blade.php)
 :: ERROR CODE STOP::

Comment: @Berto99 I rather expected an error stating that the controller does not exist, because i deleted both controllers. Yet it seems to be seeing some controller from some unknown source and reading a view page error. And this route--> Route::get('/testx', 'ControllerA@show_table'); is the only controller in my web.php routes file.

Comment: @ATSUEMMANUEL are you sure that you are looking at your project? i mean, 99% you are looking to another project or to the project in another server

Comment: @Berto99 I have checked if its another directory or server i am assessing, but i am actually on the correct server. If i change the route's path, then i get a 404 error, which means, i was actually accessing that correct route. I have cleared all possible cache, but nothing yet.

Comment: @ATSUEMMANUEL do you have this project on some online repo so that i can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your response. I finally solved the problem.
I had earlier saved a controller with the same class as the current controller while running a test, and forgot to remove it from the controller directory, this was the cause of error "Duplicate Class" in the same namespace. I simply removed the duplicate class controller and the issue was resolved.